# Sum and Running Sum, Distinct and Running Distinct

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I want to calculate sum, running sum, distinct, running distinct - preferably all in one query.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/65eff/1

```
create table test (store int, day varchar(10), food varchar(10), quantity int)
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-01', 'rice', 1
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-01', 'rice', 1
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-01', 'rice', 2
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-01', 'fruit', 2
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-01', 'water', 3
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-01', 'fruit', 1
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-01', 'salt', 2
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-02', 'rice', 1
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-02', 'rice', 2
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-02', 'fruit', 1
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-02', 'pepper', 4
```

Uniques (distinct) & Total (sum) are simple:

```
select store, day, count(distinct food) as uniques, sum(quantity) as total
from test
group by store, day
```

But I want output to be :

| store | day | uniques | run_uniques | total | run_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2021-01-01 | 4 | 4 | 12 | 12 |
| 101 | 2021-01-02 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 20 |

I tried a self-join with t.day >= prev.day to get cumulative/running data, but it's causing double-counting.

Comment: and why have you tagged this mysql?

Comment: @nbk - query for any db works. i can translate to other if needed.

Answer (score 1):

A running total will be defined so,
The cte lays the ground work, so that you have all the data to caculate the running sum.

For the running sum you can use the window function

```
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

selects only he previuous and current row, if you want bigger groups you need to adjust this

```
WITH CTE AS (select store, day, count(distinct food) uniqueItems, sum(quantity) as totalQuantity
from test
group by store, day)
SELECT store, day,uniqueItems,  SUM(uniqueItems) OVER(ORDER BY day
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
          AS RunningUniuqeTotal,totalQuantity,
  SUM(totalQuantity) OVER(ORDER BY day
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
          AS RunningTotal
          FROM CTE
```

Sample http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/65eff/11

Comment: thanks.. this gives running unique counts as 7, but it should be 5 - it's not simple sum of earlier group by. that only works for totals, not distincts.